# VBScript and QTP - strange behaviour with ArrayList vs variables

Tags: vbscript, arraylist, qtp

This might be self-explanatory, but I really don't understand.

If I try using the value in an ArrayList directly, with QTP's LoadAndRun function, it doesn't work. However, if I copy the values from the ArrayList into variables first, then it works.

This works:

```
test1 = testActionArray(1)(0)
test2 = testActionArray(1)(1)

LoadAndRunAction "C:\share\Test Automation\Flight Reservation Application\UFT Tests\" &
test1,test2, oneIteration
```

But this does NOT work:

```
LoadAndRunAction "C:\share\Test Automation\Flight Reservation Application\UFT Tests\" &
testActionArray(1)(0),testActionArray(1)(1), oneIteration
```

Why?

It completely ruins the dynamics of my code.

Update:
I just found at that THIS works:

```
LoadAndRunAction "C:\share\Test Automation\Flight Reservation Application\UFT Tests\" & 
testActionArray(1)(0),test2, oneIteration
```

So, I CAN access the arraylist directly for the FIRST argument, but not for the second. This is getting more and more strange.

UPDATE:

A little debugging, as suggested by ...

```
MsgBox  "1-0: " & testCaseList(y)(z)(0) & " [" & TypeName(testCaseList(y)(z)(0)) & "]"
MsgBox  "1-1: " & testCaseList(y)(z)(1) & " [" & TypeName(testCaseList(y)(z)(1)) & "]"
```

This yields:

```
1-0: Open_Close[Range]
1-1: CloseAllInstnces[Range]
```

The values are, as far as it's  possible to see, absolutely 100% correct. If I just hard-code 1-1, it works fine. Or, as already mentioned, copy it into a variable before using it.

Comment: What types does `LoadAndRunAction` expects? `testActionArray(1)(0)` should be type `Variant`, where `test1`, `test2` may be converted to the accepted type in the background...

Comment: Maybe. However, the strange thing is that accessing the arraylist directly works for the first aggument, but not the second one. See the update in the question.

Comment: please add some debug lines to see if the type and value changed. `Debug.Print "1-0: " & testActionArray(1)(0) & " [" & TypeName(testActionArray(1)(0)) & "]"` and `Debug.Print "1-1: " & testActionArray(1)(1) & " [" & TypeName(testActionArray(1)(1)) & "]"`

Comment: Hm. Unfortunately, I'm not good enough with QTP to see how to do this. I can add the lines, but where/how do I see the debug info?

Comment: pardon me! replace `Debug.Print` with `Wscript.Echo`, please run it with `cscript.exe` in command prompt instead of double clicking the vbs file.

Comment: I'm unable to run it from the cli, doe to some errors about invalid characters. Can it be because it is a QTP Action file? Anyway, I used MsxBox instead, and I got the values mentioned in the update. The values are both correct.

Comment: Maybe this is silly, but, typename(...) should not return String instead of Range?

Answer (score 1):

I tried executing the same way i.e accessing it from arraylist and it works for me!

```
Set a = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
Set b = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
Set c = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
b.add("CON005 - TC001 Validate Exchange - Purchase Contract Headers")
b.add("Cleanup")
c.add("CON005 - TC002 Validate Exchange - Purchase Contract Lines")
c.add("Cleanup")
a.add(b)
a.add(c)
LoadAndRunAction "X:\Test_Scripts\Contract\"& a(0)(0),a(0)(1),oneIteration
```

I am not sure whats the problem, but try debugging it as PatricK suggested..

Answer (score 1):

Try this:-

> LoadAndRunAction "C:\share\Test Automation\Flight Reservation Application\UFT Tests\" &
>   eval(testActionArray(1)(0)),eval(testActionArray(1)(1)), oneIteration

Comment: Doesn't seem to do anything. At least, the test won't run when adding eval().

Comment: have you tried watch? what value it displays for eval(testActionArray(1)(0))??

Comment: Yah, the values are seemingly identical. They're a match when comparing.